# Adding terms to custom post type - incorrect term being applied

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type, with a custom taxonomy. I am trying to apply two terms to a post.

```
$term1 = 35;
$term2 = 36;

wp_set_post_terms( $this->postId, [$term1, $term2], "my_tax");
```

This only sets the first term.
Stepping through the code, in taxonomy.php, for both items (35 and 36), the following lines both return the same data

First time

```
$term_info = term_exists( $term, $taxonomy ); // term is 35
```

Second time

```
$term_info = term_exists( $term, $taxonomy ); // term is 36
```

$term_info in both cases contains the same as below: as a consequence, only 1 term is being applied to the post

```
array(2) (
  [term_id] => (string) 35
  [term_taxonomy_id] => (string) 35
)
```

Comment: Both of your `term_exists` lines of code are using the same `$term` variable. Where are you setting this?

Comment: Those two lines are within wp core : taxomony.php - they are looping through the array which I am passing in

Comment: So in your actual code where are `$term1` and `$term2` being defined? Are you using this actual code with the IDs `35` and `36`, or is this just an example?

Comment: They are being sent like this : wp_set_post_terms( $this->localPostId, [35,36],"my_tax", true);
If I do this : 
            $t1 = term_exists( 35, "my_tax" );
            $t2 = term_exists( 36, "my_tax" );

Both $t1 and $t2 are an array like this.
array(2) (
  [term_id] => (string) 35
  [term_taxonomy_id] => (string) 35
)
Where $t2 should have 36 values ( I believe)

Comment: But are you literally using the integers 35 and 36, or are these values dynamic from somewhere else?

Comment: Originally set from elsewhere, but have been trying directly like this : wp_set_post_terms( $this->localPostId, [35,36],"my_tax", true);

Answer (score 0):

Did you try explicitly setting the term array?
And set `append` to true?

```
$terms = array( 35, 36 ); 
wp_set_post_terms( $this->postId, $terms, "my_tax", true );
```

Comment: Thanks - tried this and just the same